# Open custom app with a payload using a URL

Tags: javascript, url, redirect, payload

If this heading is not clear, I’ll clarify. Before that I have to mention that this question is not a homework but I’m curious to make this kind of an application. But couldn’t verify whether following problem can be solved. So please help me to verify whether this is possible before I start my project.

Let’s say I have a custom developed app which select best image of the week of a weekly competition. Also users can vote and share voted images on facebook. However let’s say there are two persons called X and Y. X has already installed the app and he can vote and share images. And when it comes to Y, it has two scenarios.

1) Y also have the app installed. So when she click the URL X shared, this URL should open the installed app and should view the relevant image with details such as votes and shares.

2) Y still have not downloaded the app. So URL should bring her to App Store or Play store based on mobile platform.

Second scenario has a solution. But when it comes to first one, how can I push the payload ( details of images and content) with the link to show required details whenever app completes loading? I went through lots of articles but still couldn’t find a solution. Can someone help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution for my need.

It's better to call an API to get data I need using an image ID which is unique to each images. So each link of an image contains the app URL with image ID. So when app opens by an external link,Which can be captured by using Deep Link ([React native Linking Library](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/linking)) and API call will make to the backend and get all relevant data.

[This](https://medium.com/react-native-training/deep-linking-your-react-native-app-d87c39a1ad5e) tutorial shows all relevant steps to do that.